# Problem connecting a Socket.io client in a Unity3d project configured with MRTK2

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, socket.io, windows-mixed-reality, socket.io-client

```
hi, i'm trying to implement a socket.io client inside a unity3d project configured with mrtk2.
Using the library recommended by Socket.io for a C# client I was able
to establish the connection to the server, but as soon as I insert the
code inside a Unity3d project configured with MRTK2 with the appropriate
[SocketIoCLient][1](https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp) library,
the client does not connect it connects to the server without throwing any exception or error,
can anyone help me?
```

I've included the library inside the project via NuGet to manage the dependencies, the only client that didn't throw me any exceptions with the MRTK2 configuration is SocketIOClient.NetFx 2.0.2.10
NuGet\Install-Package SocketIOClient.NetFx -Version 2.0.2.10

I use a server for Socket.io written in Node.js which essentially prints a string when a client connects, and as tested the client I made and the server only work if the Unity3d project hasn't been configured for MRTK2

Comment: MRTK has no network-related content, and you can see all its features from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/?view=mrtkunity-2022-05. For Unity projects on HoloLens, you can find log files in **Device Portal->System->File explorer->LocalAppData->[ProjectName]->TempState**.

Comment: When packaging the Unity project, please check whether **InternetClient**, **InternetClientServer** and **PrivateNetworkClientServer** are included in **Edit->Project Settings->Player->UWP->Publishing Setting->Capabilities**. And when deploying the solution to the device please double check whether these are also included in **Package.appxmanifest->Capabilities**.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I don't currently own a Hololens 2 device so I haven't tested a deployment yet, I checked the inclusion of InternetClient, InternetClientServer and PrivateNetworkClientServer, but once I added them the result didn't change.
I would like to understand if it is possible to somehow connect to a server. or at least if there is a vague possibility of making this client for Socket.io.

Comment: The network and web services currently supported by the Universal Windows Platform are listed in [Networking and web services - UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/). For Socket.IO, although it is built on top of WebSockets, the official does not clearly indicate whether it is supported. You can consult further in the corresponding channel.

Comment: Also, you mentioned that you didn't deploy the project to the device. Are you testing on the emulator? It should be noted that UWP does not support loopback testing by default, please refer to [Interprocess communication (IPC) - UWP applications | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#loopback) for more information.